# What is the sequence of calls of copy constructor in a multi-level inheritance?

Tags: c++

I have been trying to figure this out rigorously. Given three classes inheriting from each other, how does the sequence work? 
For eg: Classes Vehicle->Car->Mercedes

Comment: Base class first, always.

Comment: Given `class Vehicle`, `class Car : public Vehicle`, and `class Mercedes : public Car`, `Vehicle` is constructed first, then `Car`, then `Mercedes`

Comment: What have you tried?  It seems to me you could write the 3 classes, and add a std::cout into each ctor ... and observe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough to create MCVE ...

```
#include <chrono>
// 'compressed' chrono access --------------vvvvvvv
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock  HRClk_t; // std-chrono-hi-res-clk
typedef HRClk_t::time_point                 Time_t;  // std-chrono-hi-res-clk-time-point
typedef std::chrono::milliseconds           MS_t;    // std-chrono-milliseconds
typedef std::chrono::microseconds           US_t;    // std-chrono-microseconds
typedef std::chrono::nanoseconds            NS_t;    // std-chrono-nanoseconds
using   namespace std::chrono_literals;          // support suffixes like 100ms, 2s, 30us

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class Vehicle_t
{
public:
   Vehicle_t () { std::cout << "\n  Vehicle_t" << std::flush;   }
   ~Vehicle_t () = default;
};

class Car_t
   : public Vehicle_t
{
public:
   Car_t () { std::cout << "\n  Car_t" << std::flush;   }
   ~Car_t () = default;
};

class Mercedes_t
   : public Car_t
{
public:
   Mercedes_t () { std::cout << "\n  Mercedes_t" << std::flush;   }
   ~Mercedes_t () = default;
};


int main(int , char** )
{
   int retVal = -1;
   {
      Time_t start_us = HRClk_t::now();

      Mercedes_t  m;

      retVal = 0;

      auto  duration_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_us);

      std::cout << "\n\n  duration  " << duration_us.count() << " us" << std::endl;
   }

   return(retVal);
}
```

With output

```
Vehicle_t
Car_t
Mercedes_t
```

Notes for the beginner:

1. I'm sure you have heard it before, "execution begins at 'main'".  This code does too.
2. Thus the statement, "Mercedes_t  m;" is 1st (for this class hierarchy).  It shows the invocation of the "Mercedes_t" ctor (the most derived) is invoked first.

Remember, all methods (and functions) have both an entry and an exit.

3. The most derived ctor invokes "Car_t" ctor, which invokes "Vehicle_t" ctor.
4. The output shows that "Vehicle_t" ctor cout statement finishes first.  And thus you may infer that this ctor finishes first.
5. The output shows that the next ctor to finish is "Car_t", and then "Mercedes_t"

Summary

- the most base class is invoked last, but finishes first.
- the most derived class is invoked first, but finishes last.

> ```
> ctor Entry/Invocation sequence:   Mercedes_t -> Car_t -> Vehicle_t
> ctor Exit/ctor completion seq :   Vehicle_t  -- Car_t -- Mercedes_t
> ```

---

update - 11/19/2017

I think most of my answer is about implementation details.  It occurred to me that such 'proof' as I provided above is insufficient.  (and contradicts one or more alternate answers).

The more convincing 'proof' is to inspect the assembly.  The following is from code some what different than my MCVE above, but still has recognizable names.  FYI - My system is Ubuntu 15.10, and g++ reports (Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~15.10) 5.2.1.

Using gdb, I set break point at main (i.e. b main), issued run, then used the command

> (gdb) disassemble /m

and found

> ```
> 154      {
> 155         Mercedes_t  m; // invoke Mercedes_t ctor
>    0x00000000004019e2 <+40>:  lea    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
>    0x00000000004019e6 <+44>:  mov    %rax,%rdi
>    0x00000000004019e9 <+47>:  callq  0x40214a <Mercedes_t::Mercedes_t()>
>    0x00000000004019ee <+52>:  lea    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
> ```

This confirms that the first call to create the object is the 
< Mercedes_t::Mercedes_t() > ctor, i.e. the most derived ctor is called first.

Next, from the same type of disassembly of the Mercedes_t ctor, you can see the call to < Car_t::Car_t() >.

```
Dump of assembler code for function Mercedes_t::Mercedes_t():
91     Mercedes_t () : initLineNum (log(__LINE__)) // Mercedes_t ctor init
   0x000000000040214a <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040214b <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000040214e <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000402152 <+8>: mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
=> 0x0000000000402156 <+12>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000040215a <+16>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000040215d <+19>:    callq  0x4020ec <Car_t::Car_t()>
   0x0000000000402162 <+24>:    mov    $0x5b,%edi
   0x0000000000402167 <+29>:    callq  0x401616 <log(int)>
   0x000000000040216c <+34>:    mov    %eax,%edx
   0x000000000040216e <+36>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000402172 <+40>:    mov    %edx,0x8(%rax)
```

Enough for me.  I strongly recommend you learn gdb.

But again, I think these might be implementation details.

---

update - 11/20/2017
Added code to identify copy ctor sequence.

I added the copy ctor to each class (after default ctor, before dtor):

```
Vehicle_t(const Vehicle_t& /*rhs*/){
   std::cout << "\n  Vehicle_t(rhs) " << std::flush; }//Vehicle_t copy ctor (3)

Car_t(const Car_t& rhs) : Vehicle_t(rhs) {
   std::cout << "\n  Car_t(rhs) " << std::flush; }  // Car_t copy ctor (3)

Mercedes_t(const Mercedes_t& rhs) : Car_t(rhs) {
   std::cout << "\n  Mercedes_t(rhs) " << std::flush; }  // Mercedes_t copy ctor (3)
```

Added 2 lines to main, after default ctor, and before "retVal = 0;"

```
  Mercedes_t  m;    // invoke default ctor

  std::cout << "\n";

  Mercedes_t m2(m); // invoke copy ctor

  retVal = 0;
```

The output now looks like:

```
  Vehicle_t
  Car_t
  Mercedes_t

  Vehicle_t(rhs) 
  Car_t(rhs) 
  Mercedes_t(rhs)
```

This is the same sequence as default ctors.

I also used gdb and the "disassemble /m" command and inspected the assy.   The invocation sequence matches the default ctor.

Comment: I'll leave determining the dtor sequence to the interested.

Comment: In the new code, I added a data attribute to each class, and the init list invokes log(int) to fill the value ... you can see in (the dump of) Mercedes_t ctor that log (in the init list) is called after the return from Car_t ctor.  Thus, the evident ctor 'pattern' is a) call my parent ctor, b) perform my init list, c) perform my body.

Comment: Oops.  Finally noticed 'copy ctor' in the post title.  My bad.  The MCVE I created was about the 'default' ctor, but copy-ctor is also a reasonable question.

Comment: Just found in gdb manual about disas cmd: "The /m option is deprecated as its output is not useful when there is either inlined code or re-ordered code. The /s option is the preferred choice. "

Answer (score 1):

> What is the sequence of calls of copy constructor

The order is same as for other constructors.

- virtual bases
- non virtual bases
- members
- constructor body

If there are multiple direct bases or members, they are constructed in order of declaration.

In between each sub-object construction, an initializer list expression may be executed for the next sub-object.

> For eg: Classes Vehicle->Car->Mercedes

If `Car` is a base of `Mercedes`, then the `Car` base-sub-object is constructed before the contructor body of `Mercedes` is executed. If `Vehicle` is base of `Car`, then the `Vehicle` base-sub-object is constructed before the constructor body of `Car` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are always executed from bottom to top, so first Vehicle, next Car and finally Mercedes.
The reason for this behavior is that the child classes may use variables of the base class so those have to be initialized first.

Destructors go the same way back: first Mercedes then Car and finally Vehicle, for much the same reasons.

Answer (score 1):

First bases, explicit and inherited, are constructed, then member variables, both in left-to-right order. So, if you have

```
class Base0;
class Subbase;
class Base1: Subbbase;
struct Der: Base0, Base1 {
    Der();
    Type member1;
    Type member2;
};
```

then the order of initialization is Base0 -> Subbase -> Base1 -> member1 -> member2, then goes the ctor body (by which moment all bases and members have already been initialized).

Destructor works in reverse: body -> member2 -> member1 -> Base1 -> Subbase -> Base0.